# as.POSIXct() yields "ambiguous format" error for some dates but not for others

Tags: r, date, posixct

I encountered an error with this line:

```
> format(as.POSIXct("1982-04-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Which is strange, because most other dates work, e.g.:

```
> format(as.POSIXct("1982-04-02"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
[1] "04/02/1982"

> format(as.POSIXct("1982-03-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
[1] "03/01/1982"

> format(as.POSIXct("1980-04-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
[1] "04/01/1980"
```

Error also occurs with:

```
format(as.POSIXct("1981-04-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
format(as.POSIXct("1983-04-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
format(as.POSIXct("1984-04-01"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

How is that possible?

Comment: For me all of them work - `R 4.1.1`

Comment: I do not get that error. This is likely due to your locale and/or timezone. Can you report those, please? (I'm using win10, R-4.0.5, US/Eastern TZ, locale all `English_United States.1252`.)

Comment: These dates probably correspond to switches to/from daylight saving time in your locale. Why are you using `as.POSIXct`? If you are working with dates (and not date-times) you should use `as.Date`.

Comment: I was suspecting it has something to do with this, because this line worked for me before but I recently changed my timezone. 
UTC+03:00 Minsk
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) @Roland: My original data input is actually like that: "1982-04-01T00:00:00Z" I simplified it for the post here.

Comment: Can you post what `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` gives?

Comment: You can do `as.Date("1982-04-01T00:00:00Z")` without any issues. Alternatively, specify `tz = "UTC"`.

Comment: Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"): "English_United States.1252". Thanks @Roland, I just found that answer as well, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments pointing on the timezone/locale of my computer, I found a solution that suits my purposes:

```
format(as.POSIXct("1982-04-01", tz = "GMT"),format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

I still don't understand why this error occurs just for some dates, though.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/belarus/minsk?year=1984

Comment: 1984-04-01 00:00:00 didn't happen in Minsk's local timezone.